# Yii2 where() variable condition

Tags: yii2

I want when `currency = 'sum'` sort by and `Where(['between', 'price', $min_price, $max_price]) and when currency = 'y.e.' sort by andWhere(['between', 'price', $min_price*2, $max_price*2])`. How to write the `sql` query in `yii2`?

```
$anmt_t = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select(['*'])
    ->from('anmt')
    ->where(['status' => 'confirmed'])
    ->andWhere(['between', 'price', $min_price, $max_price, when (currency = 'sum')])
    ->andWhere(['between', 'price', $min_price*2, $max_price*2, when (currency = 'y.e.')])
    ->all();
```

Comment: and from where you get `currency = 'sum' or 'y.e.'` ?

Comment: from the database

Comment: from the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) :

```
$anmt_t = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select(['*'])
        ->from('anmt')
        ->where(['status' => 'confirmed'])
        ->andWhere('
            CASE
                WHEN currency = "sum" THEN price BETWEEN :mp1 AND :mx1
                WHEN currency = "y.e." THEN price BETWEEN :mp2 AND :mx2
            END
        ')
        ->params([
            'mp1' => $min_price,
            'mx1' => $max_price,
            'mp2' => $min_price * 2,
            'mx2' => $max_price * 2,
        ])
        ->all();
```

Not tested

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally favor using Yii2, rather than writing a long query

```
$condition = currency == 'y.e.' ? ['between', 'price', $min_price *2, $max_price*2] : ['between',  'price', $min_price, $max_price];
```

then

```
$anmt_t = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select(['*'])
    ->from('anmt')
    ->where(['status' => 'confirmed'])
    ->andWhere($condition)
    ->all();
```